# Удаление символов из строки с условием

Tags: python

Всем привет.

Пример: Удалить все запятые, которые стоят перед первой точкой. И заменить плюсом все цифры 3, которые стоят после первой точки.

Написал вот такой кусок кода, дальше не знаю, как поставить ограничение:

```
S = input(': ')
S = S.replace('3', '+')
S = S.replace(',', '')
print(S)
```

Answer (score 1):

можно воспользоваться срезами:

```
s = 'a3a3a,b3b3.c3c3,d3d3d3.e3e3e3.'    
idx = s.index('.')    
res = s[:idx].replace(',','') + s[idx:].replace('3','+')    
print(res)
```

результат:

```
a3a3ab3b3.c+c+,d+d+d+.e+e+e+.
```

Answer (score 1):

> Удалить все запятые,которые стоят перед первой точкой...
>   заменить плюсом все цифры 3,которые стоят после первой точки.

```
before_dot, dot, after_dot = input_text.partition('.')
result = (before_dot.replace(',', '')
          + dot 
          + after_dot.replace('3', '+'))
```

Это продолжает работать и для ввода, который не содержит точки.

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так должно быть:

```
tmp_str = S.split(".", 1)
print(".".join([tmp_str[0].replace(",", ""), tmp_str[1].replace("3", "+")]))
```

Comment: Спасибо!А почему оно точку удаляет?

Comment: Исправил код - больше не удаляет - это просто копипаст был немного кривой